# I am trying to get the latest version of a package from the search.maven.org, but getting an error

Tags: php, json

> "Error: Failed to retrieve data from the Maven repository"

while retrieving the latest version number from the search.maven.org.
Written the following php code which I will modify for all the other packages.

```
<?php
    $url = "https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=a:angus-activation-project&rows=1&wt=json";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($response === false) {
        echo "Error: Retrieving data from the Maven repository failed";
    } else {
        $data = json_decode($response);
    if ($data === null || !property_exists($data, 'response') || count($data->response->docs) == 0) {
        echo "Error: Failed to retrieve the latest version of the artifact from the Maven repository";
    } else {
        $latestVersion = $data->response->docs[0]->v;
        echo "Latest version is" . $latestVersion;
    }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0");
```

If you using curl with default user-agent, maven return 403 forbidden. With this your request looks like firefox

Comment: This is also not working.